# jQuery active inactive button globally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple of buttons has active and inactive class. I want to make it a shorter code and make it globally. Please help me how to do it. and also added an element which is show and hide for every clicking button has active.

```js
$('.show-btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.hide-btn').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-thanks').removeClass('inactive')
})
$('.hide-btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.show-btn').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-thanks').addClass('inactive')
})
$('.approve').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.disapprove').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-approve').removeClass('inactive')
})
$('.disapprove').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.approve').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-approve').addClass('inactive')
})
$('.agree').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.disagree').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-agree').removeClass('inactive')
})
$('.disagree').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.agree').removeClass('active')
    $('.p-agree').addClass('inactive')
})
```

```html
<style>
.active{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
.inactive{display: none;}
.btn{padding: 5px 20px;}
div{margin-top:20px;}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="show-btn btn">Show</button>
  <button class="hide-btn btn">Hide</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-thanks inactive">Thank you</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="approve btn">Approve</button>
  <button class="disapprove btn">Disapprove</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-approve inactive">Approve</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="agree btn">Agree</button>
  <button class="disagree btn">Disagree</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-agree inactive">Agree</p>
</div>
```

All I want to achieve is a less code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to access DOM elements as mentioned below:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('p').toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

```html
<style>
.active{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
.inactive{display: none;}
.btn{padding: 5px 20px;}
div{margin-top:20px;}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="show-btn btn">Show</button>
  <button class="hide-btn btn">Hide</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-thanks inactive">Thank you</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="approve btn">Approve</button>
  <button class="disapprove btn">Disapprove</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-approve inactive">Approve</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="agree btn">Agree</button>
  <button class="disagree btn">Disagree</button>
  <br>
  <p class="p-agree inactive">Agree</p>
</div>
```